# Extracting the value from SQLite query as integer in Python

Tags: python, sqlite

I made a SQLite query in Python like that:

```
SharesOwned = db.execute("SELECT SUM(Shares) FROM transactionTable WHERE Share='FB'")

print(SharesOwned)
if sharesOwned < sharesToSell:
    return errorMessage("You don't own that many shares of FB")
```

It prints:

```
[{'SUM(Shares)':10}]
```

Then it gives me this error:

```
TypeError: "List indices must be integers or slices not str"
```

How can I extract the number as an integer?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like SharesOwned is a list of dictionaries. To return the number of shares you need to do the following in this particular case:

```
SharesOwned[0]['SUM(Shares)']
```

SharesOwned[0] accesses the first element of the list, in this case a dictionary {'SUM(Shares)':10}. Now you just need to lookup the value by key - 'SUM(Shares)' in this case.

Additionally, it looks like you have a typo in sharesOwned, s should be capitalized.

Answer (score 1):

Try below changes :
Update your query:

```
SELECT SUM(Shares) AS total FROM transactionTable WHERE Share='FB'
```

Then access SharedOwned:

```
if SharedOwned[0]['total']<sharesToSell:
```